# Moving sharepoint from one Windows Server 2012 R2 to another

Tags: sharepoint-server, migration, windows-server

I have created sharepoint sites in my Windows server 2012 R2.

Now I wanted to install windows server R2 in another Machine(Computer) and then move my sharepoint sites plus farm there.

Is that possible guys?

Comment: Is this a single server farm (i.e. SQL is running on the same server, or is it a separate SQL server)? Can you provide more information on your setup please?

Comment: it's a single server farm @AndyDawson. Where I have installed sharepoint 2013. But now we have bought another faster machine,  in that machine I have installed windows server R2 and I want to move the files and everything there... So the source is "Windows Server 2012" and destination is still "Windows Server 2012"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is certainly possible, but it involves more than just copying some files around.

You'll need to migrate the farm from the old server to the new server. If you had a separate SQL Server, you could have installed SharePoint (to the same patch level) on the new server, joined this server to the farm, enabled the required services, then removed the old server from the farm to perform the migration. As the SQL Server is running on the same server however, this is a little more complicated.

There are a couple of routes to doing what you need to do:

- Clone the disks from the old server to the new server. Depending upon the hardware differences between the two servers, this might work, but I've had little success trying this route in the past.
- Create a new farm on the new server, then migrate the settings and the contents to the new farm.

The second option has two possible routes. The first is to use the SharePoint backup and restore functionality to migrate the settings to the new farm. Instructions for doing this can be found at [https://technet.microsoft.com](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff627859(v=office.15).aspx). Using this procedure, you create a new farm with a configuration database only, then create a settings-only backup from your production farm and restore this to the second farm. You will also need to copy the content databases form your production farm to the second farm and attach them to the content web applications. There are some simple instructions for this part at [https://sharepointzee.wordpress.com](https://sharepointzee.wordpress.com/2011/10/19/how-to-move-your-sharepoint-2010-database-to-a-test-farm-with-a-different-url/) (note these instructions are for SharePoint 2010, but the steps are the same).

You second method is to create another farm with the same settings - build a new farm (ideally using PowerShell) taking the service application and content databases from the source farm to the new farm a part of the build process. When creating a service application for example, if you specify the name of a database that already exists on the SQL Server used for the farm that is the correct type (and suitable version), this database will be used for the service application and therefore all settings and data that are included in the database will effectively be migrated to the new farm for the service application you've just created. Obviously your new farm will have to be either the same patch level or newer than the source farm. This latter method requires more knowledge of SharePoint, but is likely to generate you a more suitable farm for your organisation.

Comment: will I need to install sharepoint 2013 to the destination server?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to install SQL Server, then the SharePoint pre-requisites and the SharePoint binaries, then patch up to at least the same patch version as the source farm.

Comment: All right.. but what do you mean by  "patch up to at least the same patch version as the source farm"...

Comment: To  able to bring the content databases over to the new farm, the new farm needs to be at the same patch (i.e. build) level as the farm from which you're copying the content databases. Have a look at the build number of your farm in Central Administration on the old farm and then compare that to the list at http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=346 to see which patch(es) you'll need to install on the new farm to bring it to the same level. So you'd install the SharePoint pre-reqs, then the SharePoint binaries, then the required patches to get ready to build the new farm.